# Get Infos (e.g. amount, currency..) from contactless reader

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard, contactless-smartcard

I have managed to read a `transaction event` from the `contactless reader`, using

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.gsma.services.nfc.action.TRANSACTION_EVENT" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    <data android:scheme="nfc" />
</intent-filter>
```

Now my activity opens, and I'm stuck in that point because I thought I would have some kind of data in my `Intent` like the `amount` or the need to `enter PIN`, but that didn't happen.

Can any point me to a direction or am I missing something here ?

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

The `TRANSACTION_EVENT` will only point you to that applet that was invoked on the secure element (i.e. there should be an intent extra containing the applet AID). Then it's up to your application how to handle the transaction event:

- You might be able to interact with the applet to query further data about the transaction, to unlock the applet using a PIN code, etc.
- Some applications (this is typically the case for EMV payment cards) require you to query an online service about the transaction status. That online service may then provide information about the transaction about, the merchant, etc.